# linq select from list remove other rows where condition

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a list like this

```
public class RolesAccessModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryMenu { get; set; }=string.Empty;
        public string OptionMenu { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Roles { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string UserType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

The data I have in the list is like this

```
1,'PR','A','R','U'
2,'PR','A','R','U2'
3,'PR','A','R1','U5'
4,'PR','A','R1','U3'
5,'PR','A','R2','U6'
6,'PR','A','R2','U4'
```

I have 2 or more `UserType` values for the shortlist (`PrimaryMenu, OptionMenu, Role`)

I need to retrieve the shortlist (`PrimaryMenu, OptionMenu, Role`) where UserType is different from a specific value...

Using Linq I have this

```
List<RolesAccessModel> result = roleAccess.Where(p =>  p.UserType!= 'U').ToList();
```

It retrieves all list except ID=1

But I need to remove also the shortlist (`PrimaryMenu, OptionMenu, Role`) of that UserType. So ID=2 also has to be remove.

One approach is to get a list that contains the ID I want to delete, and then Exclude from the first list... the second list.

But I would like to do in just Linq operation...

It is that possible?

Comment: your LINQ query should return only 2, 4 and 6, or did you miss something in description? And going further with the logic you describe, in the end you would end up with empty list (considering the example data).

Comment: Hi @Maku I replaced data in the example... You were right.. some data was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
List<RoleAccessModel> result = roleAccess.Where(p =>
    p.UserType != 'U'
    && !roleAccess
        .Where(p2 => p2.UserType == 'U')
        .Select(p2 => p2.Roles)
        .Contains(p.Roles)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this with grouping:

```
roleAccess
    .GroupBy(p => (p.PrimaryMenu, p.OptionMenu, p.Roles))
    .Where(g => !g.Any(p => p.UserType == "U"))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```